# How to center row names and space out tables using kable

Tags: r, alignment, spacing, kable, quarto

Here is an example code where I try to display 4 tables, tables on the second row are too close from tables on the first row, is there any way I can separate them?

I would also like row names to all be aligned and centered, The last row name is never aligned with the other ones.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning= FALSE}

ex <- data.frame(B=c(10,5,12,4),
                 W=c(20,2,6,7))
row.names(ex) <- c("D", "E","A","B")

```

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

#| label: tbl-ConfusionMatrices
#| tbl-cap: "Confusion matrices for each tool with the confusion matrix for ROI 1 and the with combined ROIs"
#| tbl-subcap: 
#|   - "Tool K1"
#|   - "Tool K2"
#|   - "Tool K3"
#|   - "Tool K3"


library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
kable(ex)%>% pack_rows( index = c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs"))
kable(ex)%>% pack_rows( index = c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs"))
kable(ex)%>% pack_rows( index = c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs"))
kable(ex)%>% pack_rows( index = c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs"))
```
````

Comment: In your second chunk, you have space between the chunk header and chunk options which invalidates all of the chunk options. So make sure not to give any vertical space between the chunk header and `{r}` chunk option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some space between tables using negative value in `layout` chunk option. From the Quarto documentation on [Custom Layout](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#complex-layouts),

> The layout attribute is a 2-dimensional array where the first dimension defines rows and the second columns. In this case "layout="[[1,1], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH9TB.png)]" translates to: create two rows, the first of which has two columns of equal size and the second of which has a single column.

> You can also use negative values to create space between elements.

And the last row name `B` doesn't align with others because it is not packed under `ROIs`. So if you intend to pack both rows `A` and `B` under `ROIs`, then simply use the named vector `c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs" = 2)`.

````
---
title: "Kable Table alignment"
format: pdf
---

## Quarto

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning= FALSE}

ex <- data.frame(B=c(10,5,12,4),
                 W=c(20,2,6,7))
row.names(ex) <- c("D", "E","A","B")

```


```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
#| label: tbl-ConfusionMatrices
#| tbl-cap: "Confusion matrices for each tool with the confusion matrix for ROI 1 and the with combined ROIs"
#| tbl-subcap: 
#|   - "Tool K1"
#|   - "Tool K2"
#|   - "Tool K3"
#|   - "Tool K3"
#| layout: '[[1,1], [-1], [1,1]]'


library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
kable(ex)%>% pack_rows( index = c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs" = 2))
kable(ex)%>% pack_rows( index = c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs" = 2))
kable(ex)%>% pack_rows( index = c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs" = 2))
kable(ex)%>% pack_rows( index = c("ROI1" = 2, "ROIs" = 2))
```
````

---

[image: kable tables with space]

---